# What does the "Flag" menu entry in the Azure DevOps Pull Request view do?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, flags

When you click the 3 dots behind a pull request in the pull request view in Azure DevOps, there is a menu entry "Flag" (see picture). When you click it, there is a flag on the PR. What is this for? I didn't find any documentation or online help or even a mention of this feature.

There seems to be no way to filter flagged pull requests. Is this just to mark it as: needs special attention?

[image: Flag menu entry]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the "Flag" menu entry in the Azure DevOps Pull Request view do?

It is just a way to help us mark some special Pull Requests we are dealing with to distinguish them from other Pull Requests.

For example, when you have a lot of Pull Requests that you need to deal with, but you have questions about one of them and need more time to research or confirm, you can add a flag so that you can find it later.

Or maybe a Pull Request you've only read halfway through but was interrupted by something urgent, you can add a flag so that when you open it again you can directly find it and continue.

So, at present, this Flag is only used to help us deal with PR, its function is simple and clear, MS has not yet opened a special document for it to explain it.

Comment: so is it a flag visible only to the user that flagged it or is it visible to everyone?

Answer (score 1):

According to their [Sprint 167 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/repos/sprint-167-update#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20come%20back%20to%20a%20pull%20request%2C%20you%20can%20flag%20it%20and%20they%20will%20show%20up%20at%20the%20top%20of%20your%20list.)

> If you want to come back to a pull request, you can flag it and they will show up at the top of your list.

There are some other cool PR organization tips there, too.